# vb.NET Select distinct... how to use it?

Tags: vb.net, linq

Coming from a C# background I am a bit miffed by my inability to get this simple linq query working:

```
Dim data As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
Dim dbm As AccessDBManager = GlobalObjectManager.DBManagers("SecondaryAccessDBManager")

data = dbm.Select("*", "T町丁目位置_各務原")

Dim towns As IEnumerable(Of String()) 
        towns = data.Select(Function(d) New String() {d("町名_Trim").ToString(), d("ふりがな").ToString()})
        towns = towns.Where(Function(s) s(0).StartsWith(searchTerms) Or s(1).StartsWith(searchTerms)).Distinct()

Call UpdateTownsListView(towns.ToList())
```

I pasted together the relevant bits, so hopefully there is no error here...

`data` is loaded from an access database and is a list with the data from each row stored as a dictionary.

In this case element from `data` has a field containing the name of a Japanese town and its reading and some other stuff like the row ID etc.

I have a form with a textbox. When the user types something in, I would like to retrieve from `data` the town names corresponding to the search terms without duplicates.

Right now the results contain loads of duplicates> How can I get this sorted to only get distinct results?

I read from some other posts that a key might be needed, but how can I declare this with extension methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) uses the default equality comparer to compare values.

Your collection contains arrays of strings, so `Distinct` won't work the way you expected since two different arrays never equals each other (since `ReferenceEquals` would be used in the end).

---

A solution is to use the [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) overload which takes an [`IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx).

```
Class TwoStringArrayEqualityComparer 
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of String())

    Public Function Equals(s1 As String(), s2 As String()) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of String()).Equals
        ' Note that checking for Nothing is missing
        Return s1(0).Equals(s2(0)) AndAlso s1(1).Equals(s2(1))
    End Function

    Public Function GetHashCode(s As String()) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of String()).GetHashCode
        Return (s(0) + s(1)).GetHashCode() ' probably not perfect :-)
    End Function

End Class

...

towns = towns.Where(...).Distinct(new TwoStringArrayEqualityComparer())
```

Comment: Note that this applies to C# as well

Comment: Interesting. I thought that this would work in C# without the `IEqualityComparer` because it would perform the quality check on the values stored in the arrays rather than on the reference, as for a DB query.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try your answer yet, because I found Jon Skeet's MoreLinq in another SO question. It has a `DistinctBy` extension which solved all my problems. I will give your method a try too (but on Monday, because it's past 18.30 already and have to go home). I'll give you the answer if it works.